# Getting error when try to execute exe while of my script

Tags: python, python-3.x, barcode

I was getting some error and I don't know how to handle that error. I have created a script that is used to generate a barcode. Everything is working fine. But when I convert that script into exe. And try to use it then I am getting an error.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZGxp.jpg)

Here is my code

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
with open('somefile.jpeg', 'wb') as f:
  EAN("12347859450", writer=ImageWriter()).write(f)
```

Please help me out from this situation.

Comment: Please post the error output as text instead of an image so it's harder for others to read. That being said, my guess is that you are trying to open a file in a location that you can't actually write things (e.g. inside the packed exe), which caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your freeze method when creating the executable(cx_freeze?) is failing to include the needed dependency - in this case, looks like the FreeType library. I would investigate in that direction.